# PHP echo function inside a HTML link

Tags: php, echo

I have a PHP echo function inside of a HTML link, but it isn't working. I want to have an image location, defined in img src, be in part of the clickable link of the image. The page will have multiple images doing the same thing, so I am trying to use PHP to automate this.

```
<a href="http://statuspics.likeoverload.com/<?php echo $image; ?>">
  <img src="<?php $image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg?>" width="100" height="94" />
</a>
```

Comment: syntax error? <img src="<?php $image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg?>

Comment: `<a href="http://statuspics.likeoverload.com/<?php echo $picture; ?>"><img src="<?php $image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg?>" width="100" height="94" /></a>` Doesn't work.

Comment: yep because you have a syntax error there. just read the answer someone posted below .. or could you just explain what `<?php $image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg?>` should do?

Comment: I want the file name from the <img src= to be put at the end of this link. `http://statuspics.likeoverload.com/`

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to set a variable to a value ($image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg) and then echo it out right away, unless the variable is set elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Turn

```
<?php $image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg?>
```

into

```
<?php echo "troll/GrannyTroll.jpg"; ?>
```

?

Or provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Also, you might consider `urlencode`-ing some of those URL parameters.

**Edit:**

So you might try setting the variable beforehand:

```
<?php $image = "troll/GrannyTroll.jpg"; ?>

<a href="http://statuspics.likeoverload.com/<?php echo $image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" width="100" height="94" /></a>
```

Comment: I want the file name from the <img src= to be put at the end of this link. `http://statuspics.likeoverload.com/`

Comment: +1 but I would prefer single quotes, if I really do not need double ones: `<?php echo 'troll/GrannyTroll.jpg'; ?>`

Comment: @Tadeck Just escape the single quotes

Comment: @smott I just realized this whole code makes no sense - we echo some constant string within some HTML ;) The result is always the same and does not require PHP. But yes, using single quotes when you do not require them is not only _micro performance optimization_, but also _avoiding unexpected mistakes in the future_, like adding some dollar signs. If you do not need it, why use it? _KISS_ rule.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible. I want to have an image location, defined in img src, be in part of the clickable link of the image. The page will have multiple images doing the same thing, so I am trying to use PHP to automate this. Thank you for your help, however.

Comment: @Tadeck, well I call that future mistakes sloppiness. I did use single quotes, but then started to use double quotes since I did some Java programming, where strings are enclosed in "" and characters are ''. Maybe the same thing is applied in C, but I'm not sure at this moment.

Comment: @Luke Miles, you will just have to show us more code. I might think I know what you mean, but guessing the code is just meaningless.

Comment: @smott This is just because you got used to it, noone will punish you for that, I think ;) Yes, this is sloppiness, but most of the errors I find in someone else's code is just caused by sloppiness - if I can, I just suggest solutions that decrease the possibility of such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

So now i understand what you are trying to do.

One error is that you didn't enclose `$image=troll/GrannyTroll.jpg` with quotes like this:

`$image = 'troll/GrannyTroll.jpg';`

The second error is that you do it in the wrong order, you have to define $image first, before you use it.
That's what I believe you want to do:

```
<?php
    $image = "troll/GrannyTroll.jpg";
?>
<a href="http://statuspics.likeoverload.com/<?php echo $image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="100" height="94"/></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible. I want to have an image location, defined in img src, be in part of the clickable link of the image. The page will have multiple images doing the same thing, so I am trying to use PHP to automate this. Thank you for your help, however.